# Why is the session value changing only when the user visits the site for the first time

Tags: php, html, ajax

I wanted to add a CSRF protection to my login form by adding a hidden input field with a hashed token and comparing it on a server with a session that the token was set to. For some weird reason the SESSION value is changing when user is visiting the page for the first time. After a refresh, everything works just fine.

**Here's a run through how the code works**

1. First the user submit's his/her data on a login form which looks
   like this

login.php

```
//PHP
$_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid());

//HTML
<form id="login">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$_SESSION['token']?>">
  <input type="submit">
<form>
```

Let's say that the token value is now

> 1234567890

2. Then the form data is being sent to the server using jquery and ajax

login.js

```
$('#login').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': 'server.php',
    'dataType': 'json',
    'data': $('#login').serialize() + '&login=true',
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
    },error: function(response){
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

1. After that the server.php recieves POSTed values and starts validating the form (here's where things get funny)

server.php

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
  if($_SESSION['token'] === $_POST['token']){
    //validate rest of the form
  }else{
    //do nothing
  }
}
```

For some weird reason the $_SESSION['token'] value is now

> 098765431

And the validation fails

It only happens when the user is visiting my site for the first time, after first refresh, everything works just fine.

Could someone explain me why this could be happening and how could i get pass that? One option would be to just refresh the page when token check fails but it still bothers me because this shouldn't be happening at all.

I also tried adding session setting in a root file that both files are including at the beginning.

Comment: Ran a quick test on my local dev box - works fine as long as you have `session_start()` at the top of both *login.php* and *server.php*

Comment: I have it in a init.php file which both files are including from the beginning of the code. You can try by closing the browser and then trying again. It's only bugging on first visit.

Comment: It's not bugging out on first visit for me though - I've got *server.php* just returning a simple JSON holding the `$_SESSION['token']` and `$_POST['token']` values, one example response, first load using a different browser: `{"session_token":"dbc7d0386f91bec433bb4422ccbdc451","posted_token":"dbc7d0386f91bec433bb4422ccbdc451"}` values are the same.

Comment: Thats so weird, i don't understand it then.  Could it be because i'm running this script on my local server or something? It happens on all broswers

Comment: Your init file hasn't got something in it that terminates the session anywhere has it?

Comment: Nope, init just has 
session_start();

and some configuration data

Comment: I had a similar case where the problem happened due to output being sent before the `session_start()` was called so the cookie would be discarded. You can test if the behavior changes if you either enable output_buffering in php.ini or start output buffering via `ob_start();` at the very beginning of your main PHP file.

Comment: Are you modifying the session token in the Ajax requested server.php file?

Comment: Output buffering didn't fix the issue and i'm not modifying the session token anywhere else.